# Open deep links with Appium?

Tags: android, python, selenium, appium, deep-linking

Is it possible to test deep links with Appium?  We have a webpage with deep links on it that we can load on in mobile Chrome.  When we tap on the links, they take us to a page within our app.

However, when Appium taps on the links, nothing happens.  As far as I can tell the tap/click event is happening, but for some reason the behavior is different and it won't load up the page in our app.

Does anyone know why this won't work?  Why would an Appium tap be different from an actual one in this case?  Is there any workaround for this issue?

EDIT: I should clarify, this is a coded Appium test written in Python.  The code is very simple:

```
link_to_tap = self.appium_driver.find_element_by_id("deeplink")
link_to_tap.click()
```

Before you ask, yes, `link_to_tap` is a valid `WebElement` which corresponds to the correct link.  `link_to_tap.click()` throws no exceptions and I can verify the click does occur.

Comment: can you debug to find if Appium is actually able to access the element? 
I guess you might be ending up trying to access an element in a WebView without changing the context. This might be helpful https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-identify-webview-elements-in-android-hybrid-app/5140/7?u=namannigam14

Comment: Also you can try with sending touch rather than a click.